# Adding Reminder Set and Reminder date while creating New task

Tags: tasks

In my org i wanted to see Reminder Set field and fields of reminder date&time....when i am creating new task....in chatter action or in global action page layouts.

So i edited Global action button page layout to add "Reminder Set" field in page layout.  But I can't see the Date & time fields of reminder...to add them in layout. Also when i create new task and i set "Reminder set" field to Checked(True)...when i see the detail page of that task...i see it unchecked (false).

Any idea how can i add those reminder date & time field on pagelayouts....also why does it override the value of the flag (reminder set) when record is created.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This capability is now available, as of the Winter'19 Release of Salesforce. You need to add the "Reminder Set" field to your quick action layouts.

For more details, see the [Winter'19 Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_sales_productivity_tasks_reminders_quick_action.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The reminder date\time fields aren't manually added to the layout. You only add the 'Reminder Set' field and checking the box automatically shows the reminder date and time.

But [reminders aren't supported in global actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tasks_enable_task_notifications.htm&type=0).  You can add the 'Reminder Set' field to the layout for the action but it does not do anything when checked.

Comment: Yeah...that is exactly what is happening........was just hoping for any workaround this limitation

Comment: I don't know of any way to work around it. If it's worth the effort, you can create a Lightning component action instead of a quick action. That will give you more control over the behavior but it's more effort to build and maintain than a quick action.